# How to add additional fields to ngForm before submit?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How can I add some additonal fields to my form right before it goes out?

```
this.forma = { 'date': this.selectedDate };
```

form.ts

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    console.log(f);
}
```

form.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(forma)" #forma="ngForm" method="post">
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>First name, last name*</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" value="" minlength="8" name="subject" ngModel #subject="ngModel"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want some additional fields in your HTML-Template or the underlying forma-object?

Comment: I want to add some additional fields in a form object, one of them being { 'date': this.selectedDate };

Comment: You can use this.forma.controls.ush(new FormControl(...)) But I supouse you really want to send an object like myobject={...forma.value,date:this.selectedDate}

Comment: @Eliseo, `controls` is an instance of `AbstractControl` not array

Comment: Sorry use addControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add some additonal fields to my form right before it goes
>   out?

If you want add additional fields to **NgForm**, you only can add **FormControl/FormGroup** of **NgModel** type, which means you need to have some element in template with ngModel directive. Example:

```
class SomeComponent{

@ViewChild('myControl') myControl: NgModel;
...
onSubmit(f: NgForm){
   f.addControl(myControl);
}
...
}
```

Component template:

```
    <input #myControl="ngModel" [name]="formInputName" [id]="formInputName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
```

But you can add fields to **FormGroup**. This case may useful when you need render different control types dynamically.

[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-asdads)

[Official guide](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form#dynamic-forms)

**Update**: fix formControlName bindings

Comment: Looks like it should work, trying to implement right now